# jQuery last line refuses to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been learning javascript for over a month now and this is the first time I've ran into a brick wall and can't figure out why something just doesn't run.

I'm trying to do a horizontal menu with divs that float to the side on button click. It all works fine up until the initial loop is finished and upon clicking "next" when contactSec div is active, the initial homeSec div simply refuses to float back into view.

```js
$( next ).click(function() {
if (homeSec.style.display == "block") {
    $(homeSec).animate({left: "-1900px", opacity: 0}, 1000).queue(function() {   
        displayOff()
        displayAbout()
        $(aboutSec).animate({left: "0px", opacity: 1});
        });
} else if (aboutSec.style.display == "block") {
        $(aboutSec).animate({left: "-1900px", opacity: 0}, 1000).queue(function() {
        displayOff()
        displayContact()
        $(contactSec).animate({left: "0px", opacity: 1});
        });
} else if (contactSec.style.display == "block") {
        $(contactSec).animate({left: "-1900px", opacity: 0}, 1000).queue(function() {
        displayOff()
        displayHome()
        $(homeSec).animate({left: "0px", opacity: 1});
        });
}
});
```

displayOff(); sets the display to "none" and resets the style.left to "1900px" and displayHome(); sets style.display to "block".

Now when I copy and paste the code manually to the console, line by line, homeSec div floats into view just fine, but it does not happen when I click the next button after contactSec. It just gets stuck at the edge of the screen.

Comment: If you remove `queue` and use the callback that's already available in `animate`, what happens

Comment: That actually fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that when using `queue` you have to either `dequeue` or call `next()`